D7->BackDrop Theming migration problem
The D7-Backdrop migration messes up Civi theming in Backdrop.  If I install Backdrop 'vanilla' and then install Civi, theming is good, even better than good.  However, when I migrate a site from D7 that includes CiviCRM it gets messed up with Civi sitting in the middle of the screen as though there was a left sidebar (which there wasn't).  I've tried switching to Bartik before migration but that hasn't helped. I'd like to be able to run the D7 to Backdrop migration task without it touching themes at all. This is probably a question more for Backdrop as Civi but I wondered how others had managed this.

If you look at the layouts, are they set to use the same layout template in both of these cases? You may just need to select a different layout template for the Civicrm layout.

Not sure I understand how themes and layouts relate?  What theme/layout do you use for Civi?

In Backdrop, Layouts are broken out separately from themes. By default I believe the Boxton layout is used which wouldn't have sidebars.
https://docs.backdropcms.org/documentation/layouts-and-templates

The way I migrated D7 database to Backdrop was not in accordance with  the docs here https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switching-cms/drupal-to-backdrop/ So I uninstalled Civi as a Drupal module and then migrated the D7 database.  Then I followed these instructions and all is OK.  Doing the D7 to Backdrop migration with Civi as an installed module is not the  way to do it.  The downside of uninstalling it is that the Civi permissions don't get migrated, although the roles do.  But that's no big deal as long as you know it.  Now happily running under Backdrop...

There is a layout for CiviCRM pages provided by the civicrmtheme module which is part of the CiviCRM Backdrop package.
Something in the d7->bd migration causes problems with that.  However, if you disable and uninstall, then reinstall that module (Functionality > List Modules) then you should see the Default CiviCRM Layout under Structure > Layouts.  Disable/Enable is not sufficient - you need to Disable/Uninstall/Install.
